# Group and count items

Tags: linq

I have a .csv file (words.csv) containing 5000 words seperated by commas. Most of the strings are repeated values.

Can I use LINQ to do the following:

A. group common words together and show count of repeated words

so if apple has been repeated 5 times and banana 3 times..it should display as

apple - 5
banana - 3
and so on

B. Create another text file with duplicates removed.

Answer (score 6):

Sure, here's the LINQ syntax in C#:

```
from word in words
group word into occurrences
select new
{
    Word = occurrences.Key,
    Count = occurrences.Count()
}
```

Or in "pure" C# method calls:

```
words.GroupBy(w => w)
     .Select(o => new 
                  { 
                     Word = o.Key,
                     Count = o.Count()
                  });
```

And to create a distinct list of words you just use the Distinct operator:

```
words.Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a distinct keyword in Linq that you could use.

http://www.shawson.co.uk/codeblog/linq-distinct/